# How is media document entity different from file document entity?

Tags: media, files

I hope this is the right place for my question as I want to understand media document a bit more.

I'm working on a library website. Each book can have one or more files. Each book file should accept either local file, external link or both.

I think now it is possible to do that with media entity document or file entity.

I just don't see the difference and the better option for my case.

Any thoughts will be great.